# Make Outgoing Call From Using Twilio API in Python

Tags: python-2.7, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call

I tried to making outgoing call to end user using twilio python for communicating both user as normal call but somehow it will not worked.Suggestion would be great help. Thanks

Comment: What did you try? Can you share the code you used, otherwise it's hard to see what you've done wrong. Also, when you say it won't work, what exactly about it doesn't work?

Comment: Hello, Thank you for comment. Below is my code but it just for called to user and just play normal voice message and it works perfect.          client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)

call = client.api.account.calls\
      .create(to="+14085551234",  
              from_="+12125551234", 
              url="http://twimlets.com/holdmusic?Bucket=com.twilio.music.ambient")

Comment: Could you update your question if you add things, as comments are not the best place. Thanks for sharing code that does work, but if something doesn't work I need to see that code and I need to know exactly what isn't working so that I can help.